# Using a pre-existing PHP script to upload images to a server

Tags: c#, php, winforms, networking

I'm creating a winform application where I need to upload image files to a central image server. Before this, there is a pre-existing php script that has been written to allow images to be uploaded to the server via a web portal. I've also been told that I can make my program access this PHP script and use its functionality.

How is that possible?

So far what I've tried is the following lines of code:

```
IPHostEntry ipHostInfo = System.Net.Dns.GetHostEntry("http://scriptlocation.html");
IPAddress ipAddress = ipHostInfo.AddressList[0];

using (TcpClient client = new TcpClient())
{
   client.Connect(ipAddress, 21);
   client.SendTimeout = 3000;
   var status = client.Connected;
   lblStatus.Text = status.ToString();
   Console.WriteLine(status);
}
```

But when I run this I get the following error;

> *No such host is known*

I'm really new to network programming like this, could someone please point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly you are simply trying to send file to http.

Consider using WebClient:

```
using(var wc = new WebClient())
{
    wc.UploadData("http://scriptlocation.html", "POST", data);
}
```

where data is file byte array;